# Django model with many to one relationship in template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I have two objects with one-to-many relationship:

```
from django.db import models

class DownloadItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    downloadItem = models.ImageField(upload_to='./images/downloadItems', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class DownloadItemSample(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='./images/downloadItemsSample', blank=True)
    downloadItem = models.ForeignKey(DownloadItem, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And in my view I am doing the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mainstore.models import DownloadItem

def index(request):
    downloads_list = DownloadItem.objects.all()
    context = {'downloads_list': downloads_list}
    return render(request, 'mainstore/index.html', context)
```

In my template I would like to get the following:

`{{ downloads_list.downloadItemSample_set.all().order_by('order')[0] }}`

I also would like to iterate over the array, but for this sample I am using the index `0`.

I was thinking to write a custom template tag, but I think this isn't the best way to do this. I think I can write a method for the `DownloadItem` model which accepts an index and returns the correct `DownloadItemSample` object, but currently I couldn't create this one neither.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would never be able to achieve `downloads_list.downloadItemSample_set` as `downloads_list` is a queryset.

One way to achieve this would be:

```
{% for download in downloads_list %}
    {{ download.get_sample_by_order }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here `get_sample_by_order` is a helper method in the class `DownloadItem` which returns the value we need.

```
class DownloadItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    downloadItem = models.ImageField(upload_to='./images/downloadItems', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_sample_by_order(self):   
        if self.downloaditemsample_set.count():
            return self.downloaditemsample_set.order_by('order')[0]
```

Comment: This is a cool solution, and I was thinking on this when I've told you that I could write a method on `DownloadItem`, but this isn't supporting the indexing. Do you also a have a solution for this?

Comment: what do you mean by suporting indexing ?

Comment: In your helper method, you're currently using the index 0 for the array when returning a value. Can this be changed as a parameter?

Comment: Oh.. for that, you can send an argument and call it as `5|download.get_sample_by_order` - but this is going to be very heavy on the database layer.

Comment: The indexing is only needed for debugging. I am going to use the `get_sample_by_order` to return the whole array and then iterate over it with a `for` template. What do you think? Is this ok?